# What might be the reasons I feel that I'm not really working?

Tags: software-industry, work-experience, projects, offices

As a software engineer. It feels quite disappointing when you are being assigned to some work that  most of the time is out of your primary skill scope. I'm not really sure the company is out of projects (i.e. less clients). It's just, I don't think my manager trusts me or my abilities to get into a project. I was checking some coworker's (with permission of course) reports and feel surprised that I'm the only one who currently handling a single, small project. I feel quite useless.

Sometimes I want to poke the manager to ask him when exactly he wants me to be involved in to some particular projects (at least the prototype) But, most of time I feel that it would be rude. I also think that it's the upper management who instructs him who to put on which the assignment, so he has little authority to do so.
Yes, Naively I would think that It's a good thing because less work and fewer duties means less responsibilities, less stress. But I'm not going to improve in this way. 
I must get in to a bigger company at some time in my career life, but I have to grow before I can do so.
So what might be the reasons I feel that I'm not really working? Other than being the only engineer in the company who is not currently handling projects.

Comment: How long have you been working here? Did you always occupy a job as software engineer in here?

Comment: Also, something is unclear to me: is your question about why you might feel like not really working? If yes, I'm not sure we can answer that here, as it feels like something only you could know. If you need help with how to ask for more tasks to do, that might be something we can address here.

Comment: As I read the OP, you seem to have two questions here: The first _"What might be the reasons I feel that I'm not really working? "_ we can't really answer here because we can't read your mind & feelings. The second one: _"How can I get involved in bigger projects and get more responsebility"_ might be a fit for The Workplace..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: Maybe you are not actually working and slacking around most of the time. Or maybe you are working but you think that your project ist unimportant and so your work is insignificant.

To answer what I think is really your question: How can you get your manager to assing you to the bigger projects / give you some more interesting work.

Simple. Finish the project you have. Put in the hours necessary, get the project done. If you are new to the company, that might as well be kind of a test. You get a small, not too important project and then your boss watches what you do. Maybe it is just something nobody really wants to do, so the newbye gets it.

Will you work in a self-reliant way? Will you make progress without being constantly pressured?

Once you have finished that project, you will get assigned new work.